# Converting a negative integer into a byte[] 8bit array for the purposes of updating Image EXIF data (GPS lat/long); Two's Complement?

Tags: arrays, geolocation, twos-complement

I have a function that will convert three integers into a byte array:

```
private static byte[] FloatToExifGps(int degrees, int minutes, int seconds)
{
    var secBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(seconds);
    var secDivisor = BitConverter.GetBytes(100);
    var bytedegree = BitConverter.GetBytes(degrees);
    byte[] rv = { (byte)degrees, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, (byte)minutes, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, secBytes[0], secBytes[1], 0, 0, secDivisor[0], 0, 0, 0 };
    return rv;     
}
```

The function SetPropertyItem only takes a byte[] where there are three rational numbers in it.

If I use:

```
FloatToExifGps(51, 47, 1234)
```

Then I will get exactly what I am after and it will convert it into a real GPS decimal.

However, if I use a negative integer then the value starts going back from 0 to 255, 254 etc owing to the byte two ranging from 0 to 255.

So for example if I try to use the function on this number:

-1.1159028

It should come out to

-1; 53; 2.7

But it will come out as

255; 53; 3.48

When I then SetPropertyItem using that array, it translates literally and I get an impossible gps lat/long:
[Picture of the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvN7p.png)

I'm fairly sure this can be solved with Two's complment, but I am now stuck. Would anyone care to help me?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it's impossible to do what I want. The way around it is setting the N E S W tag in the exif data. The value might be positive, but it will be interpretted as negative with the S tag (for south).